# Database Modeling an Email List and Report Types

Tags: ms-access, database-design, entity-relationship, email

I'm having a huge problem in modeling this problem. I'm writing a exam taking application (in MS-Access, but this isn't really relevant) and there are a few reports that need to be sent out.

The first report is sent out automatically after a person completes an exam. The second report is sent out every 2 weeks (or whatever they want to set it to).

The content of these reports contain exam information. Based on the **exam type**, certain people need to be emailed. Also, based on the **frequency** (per exam or per 2 weeks) there needs to be a differentiation as well.

I have some real reservations about how I'm setting this up. I really don't know if this is correct or not and it'll be a huge amount of work if the database schema isn't set up correctly.

The proposed schema is below:

```
-----------
|Exam List|
-----------
    \|/
     |
     |
-----------
|Exam Type|
-----------
     |
     |
    /|\
------------    -----------
|Email List|>---|Frequency|
------------    -----------
    \|/
     |
     |
-----------
|Employees|
-----------
```

What do you guys think? I'm afraid that the way the frequency is set up that it won't describe fully the data and I'll have to hack together tons of `IF` statements within Access to accomodate (something I'm trying to avoid, unlike the previous program that is being replaced by this).

Comment: How about an example -- it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this may be a start.

- A `Test` is an action of an `Employee` taking an `Exam`. An employee may take an exam several times.
- An `Exam` is of a certain `ExamType`.
- A person receiving the email (`Recipient`) is an employee too.
- Each `Recipient` can schedule (`EmailSchedule`) a different email (`Template`) for each `ExamType` at a specified `Frequency`.
- According to the `EmailSchedule`, emails are queued into the `EmailQueue` for each `Test`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are employees taking the exams?  I think you're missing at least one relationship between employees and exams (employeeExam, where you'd store things like dateExamTaken and score, and maybe a flag like resultsSent)

It might help to also include a mailSent table for auditing and debugging purposes.

Comment: It's a partial schema. There are more tables. This schema is only the (proposed) tables related to the emailing.

Comment: So an employee has multiple email lists, an exam type also has multiple email lists (not getting this one, myself,) and a frequency can apply to multiple lists.
More concrete examples would help us help you.
Can you list some of the rows you expect to see in each table?